# When we need Pointer of BOOL Variable in Objective C?

Tags: iphone

In which case we need a pointer of a BOOL variable in Objective C language?

I have a code for collapsible UITableView in which there is a function declaration:

```
- (void)toggle:(BOOL*)isExpanded section:(NSInteger)section;
```

and its definition is:

```
- (void)toggle:(BOOL*)isExpanded section:(NSInteger)section 
{
    *isExpanded = !*isExpanded; 
    NSArray *paths = [self indexPathsInSection:section];

    if (!*isExpanded)
    {
        [self.tableview deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:paths withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    }
    else 
    {
        [self.tableview insertRowsAtIndexPaths:paths withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    }
```

***isExpanded = !*isExpanded;** What is the meaning of this statement as I have never used this kind of statement in case of BOOL Variable.

Following are other two functions of same code which are called in the sequence of above function:

```
- (NSArray*)indexPathsInSection:(NSInteger)section 
{
    NSMutableArray *paths = [NSMutableArray array];
NSInteger row;
    for ( row = 0; row < [self numberOfRowsInSection:section]; row++ ) 
    {
        [paths addObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:row inSection:section]];
    }
    return [NSArray arrayWithArray:paths];
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section 
{
    return [[sectionDataArray objectAtIndex:section] count];
}
```

**sectionDataArray** is the array for number of rows in each section. I may be unclear but if you got my point please explain all this.

[Here is the link to that code](http://www.4shared.com/get/XqliTOle/Collapsible_UITableView.html)

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pointers to variables (or pointer to pointers of objects) are useful, if you want to change their value in another function. If you pass a plain `BOOL` to a method, you can use it, but if you change it, this change is only local as it was passed by value. If you pass the pointer/address of the variable instead, you can also change its real value.

This comes in handy if you need more than one return value and don't want to wrap it up in an object. It's also a common pattern in Cocoa where `NSError` variables are passed as pointers, i.e `-(BOOL) doSomethingError:(NSError **)error`.

Comment: Can I use one BOOL variable to check the state of each section of UITableView whether it is expanded or not? In my project section will be generated dynamically.

Comment: For several sections you'd wrap all your separate values up in a collection, i.e. a NSMutableArray, or you store the expanded sections in a NSMutableSet. Make sure to wrap plain values in NSNumber objects.

Answer (score 2):

It's unclear why you did have to pass the pointer to a `BOOL`. Even if you were tracking the `expanded` status of all sections using an array of `BOOL`s, I would guess setting it up as an instance variable would have been better.

```
*isExpanded = !*isExpanded;
```

This is basically flipping the value of the `BOOL`. Since you've passed a pointer, you will be able to see the flip in the caller method.

As such, the second part indulges itself in building a list of all index paths in a particular section so that the app can delete the section using `deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:` method of `UITableView`. Somehow using `deleteSections:withRowAnimation:` method could've been easier. Same thing goes for `insert..` methods.

#### An array of booleans

Assuming that you need to maintain a dynamic array of `BOOL`s. `NSMutableArray` is a proper fit.

Say, you start off with a certain number of sections that have `expanded` set to `NO`.

```
/* In the interface of the view controller */
NSMutableArray * expandedStatuses;

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray * expandedStatuses;

/* In viewDidLoad or viewWillAppear:, as needed */
self.expandedStatuses = [NSMutableArray array];
for ( int i = 0; i < numberOfSections; i++ ) {
    [self.expandedStatuses addObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO]];
}
```

Later, in your `toggle:section:` method do this,

```
/* Getting the expanded status of the section */
BOOL expanded = [[self.expandedStatuses objectAtIndex:section] boolValue];

/* Flipping the expanded status of the section */
[self.expandedStatuses replaceObjectAtIndex:section withObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:!expanded]];
```

If you are interested in deleting a particular section,

```
 [self.expandedStatuses removeObjectAtIndex:sectionIndexToDelete];
```

And if you are interested in adding,

```
 /* Adding at the end */
 [self.expandedStatuses addObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO]];

 /* Or adding it in between */
 [self.expandedStatuses insertObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO] atIndex:sectionIndexToInsertAt];
```

So `NSMutableArray` is pretty flexible to play with. You can consider it as an option to switch to.

Comment: you are right, I have to track the expanded status of all the sections in the table but the problem is in my project I have to generate the sections dynamically, so I can't have the fix number of Bool variable to check expansion of each associated section.

Comment: You can still use an `NSMutableArray` of `NSNumber`s containing `BOOL`s.

Answer (score 1):

They are intended to use `isExpanded` even after the exit of `toggle:` method with the modified value.

```
*isExpanded = !*isExpanded;
```

You could avoid using `BOOL` pointer in method by declaring `isExpanded` as the **member variable** (iVar) pf your `class` .

And use belwo

```
isExpanded = !isExpanded;
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using

```
*isExpanded = !*isExpanded;
```

You can try using

```
isExpanded[0] = !isExpanded[0];
```

Comment: It is not an array - so don't use it as one. Noone can read and understand this code later.

Comment: Do you know pointer concept???? when you do *isExpanded, it will point to first object from memory, so we can access using isExpanded[0]....

Comment: I know what pointers are. For the reader of the code, however, you communicate that isExpanded might be an array, which is just not true. So your code lies - be it semantical equivalent or not. It almost looks like a bug - why is he using [0] and not [section]? There's no way you can understand that code on its own.

Answer (score -3):

BOOL is not class type it is

```
 typedef signed char     BOOL;
```

You can not have pointer to BOOL variable.

Comment: @Jennis:Jennis, but that code made me confused and I am also doubtful about it because XCode is not giving me any error and code is running smoothly so there may be some possible case in which we may need a pointer of BOOL variable. I want to know that case.

Comment: @Eiko; Please let me know that case and clarify the condition as well. Thanks

Comment: @Eiko can you please show me example for the same in objective c considering above question keeping in mind.

Comment: Please see my answer. Pointers to variables are nothing special - just a common C language construct that has been around for ages.